# Lotus notes: Upload image to external drive

Tags: jquery, ajax, lotus-notes

I'm using Lotus Domino 8.5. I want to upload image without used File Upload Control because it upload file to database of server. So, I think I should using other way to upload image to external drive.
Who can help me?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would suggest the folloing approach:

1. Create a page / form to upload the file to a document in a notes database. My recommendation is to create a XPage with the file upload control.
2. In the database, create a scheduled agent which saves the file to the specified location on your OS

This is how I would do it - I know there must be a lot mor possibilities to achieve what you want to have.

Comment: I created form with input control html. And, use ajax post to send image data to Java agent to save on my location. But when I saved image, it's missing. I check received byte from ajax request and byte of original image, they different. 
This is my ajax:
`$.ajax( {
  url : "testJava?openAgent",
  type : "POST",
  data : document.forms[0].images.files[0],
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success : function(res) {
   document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;   
  }
 });`